# Comparaciones con variables vacias

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, lógica

Tengo un bucle for que recorre un arreglo para saber cual es el numero menor del arreglo, pero hay casos en los que el arreglo tiene todos sus elementos en tipo None menos 1 ¿Que puedo hacer para establecer el unico elemento lleno como mi variable de numero menor? Adjunto mi codigo para mejor entendimiento

```
valorestake = [takeapmin, takeapmax, enmediotakea, enmediotakec, enmediocierremin, enmediocierremax]
menortake = valorestake[0]
```

En este caso todos los valores excepto enmediocierremax son de tipo None

```
for i in valorestake:
    if i!=None:
        if i<menortake:
            menortake=i
```

Como no hay ningun valor con el cual hacer comparacion la variable menortake no se puede rellenar con el valor que deberia

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución de una sola línea:

```
menortake = min(elem for elem in valorestake if elem is not None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tu bucle de la siguiente manera:

```
lista_aux = [] #Lista Auxiliar
for i in valorestake:
    if (i is None) == False: #Si es diferente de None
        lista_aux.append(i)  #Agrega a la lista
if lista_aux: #Si la lista no esta vacia
    menortake = min(lista_aux) #Obten el menor
```

Así funciona cuando solo hay 1 solo valor. Cuando hay mas de uno compara y saca el minimo, y cuando no hay ninguno asigan `None` a `menortake`.

Suponiendo que `enmediocierremax` es igual a 7 y los demas elementos son None. El output de `print(menortake)`:

```
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Quiero dejar en `menor` el valor del menor elemento en la lista. Como la lista puede traer `None`, antes de comparar contra `menor`, necesito verificar que menor tenga algún valor. Si no tiene ninguno (`menor == None`), entonces es el primer valor real y lo uso directamente para inicializar `menor

La solución que no necesita listas auxiliares:

```
lista = [None, None, None, None, None, 4]

menor = None
for valor in lista:
    if valor is not None:
        if not menor or valor < menor:
            menor = valor

print(menor)
```

produce:

```
4
```

La solución funciona también cuando la lista trae más de un valor.

Comment: Ahora si. Gracias.